# How to split a string in an array and make an associative array with it?

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have an array "arrayServers" with values.
`String[] arrayServers;`
and when I output data in a loop

`for (int i = 0; i < arrayServers.length; i++){
      Log.i(LOG_TAG,arrayServers[i]);
}`

I get these values:

`91.134.166.76:8085
149.202.89.34:7776
176.32.36.18:7777
176.32.36.124:7777
195.201.70.37:7777
5.254.104.134:7777
176.32.37.82:7777`

How do I display this list somehow like this:

```
[IP => 176.32.37.27 PORT => 7777, IP => 54.38.156.202 PORT => 7777, IP => 51.68.208.5 PORT => 7777]
```

the port has only 4 digits

Answer (score 1):

```
class WebAddress{
    String ip;
    String port;
}

WebAddress[] webAddresses = new WebAddress[arrayServers.length];
WebAddress webAddress = new WebAddress();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayServers.length; i++){
      String strArr[] = arrayServers[i].split(":");
      webAddress.setIp(strArr[0]);
      webAddress.setPort(strArr[1]);
      webAddresses[i] = webAddress;
}
```

Then iterate over webAddresses array to get the values